# How to show image next to mouse on mouseover table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show an image next to the mouse when a visitor has the mouse over a table row. 
For every row I'd like to show another image.

For now, I only get it to work on the content within a table cell, and only for the content itself, but not for the entire row, if it has content or not.

I´m using the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    this.screenshotPreview = function() {
        /* CONFIG */
        xOffset = 0;
        yOffset = 0;
        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result
        /* END CONFIG */
        $(".screenshot").hover(function(e) {
            this.t = this.title;
            this.title = "";
            var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
            $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='" + this.rel + "' alt='Drinkbak' />" + c + "</p>");
            $("#screenshot")
                .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
            },
            function() {
                this.title = this.t;
                $("#screenshot").remove();
            }
        );
        $(".screenshot").mousemove(function(e) {
            $("#screenshot")
                .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
        });
    };

// starting the script on page load
    $(document).ready(function() {
        screenshotPreview();
    });
</script>
```

The code which does work, but only for content within table cells:

```
<tr onclick="window.open('/Drinkbak-type-B-80-geschikt-voor-rundvee-en-paarden_pr_850861?i-knop', '_blank');">
    <td class="wkekaSubject"><a title="Drinkbak" class="screenshot" rel="http://dev-jarola3-nl.softlution.com/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/Jarola-Wildkamp-Site/Jarola-Wildkamp/nl_NL/i-knoppen/850861.png">Drinkbak,<br />type B 80</a></td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption1">X</td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption4">X</td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="wkeka2Options wkekaOption7">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Here the `<a title="Drinkbak" class="screenshot" rel="http://dev-jarola3-nl.softlution.com/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/Jarola-Wildkamp-Site/Jarola-Wildkamp/nl_NL/i-knoppen/850861.png">Drinkbak,<br />type B 80</a>` element takes care of the image thumbnail.

Can someone please help me get this code to work at an entire table row?

Comment: Does the `tr` tag have `class='screenshot'`?

Comment: Tried that, it didn't help. The jsfiddle of hilarudeens did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targetting "screenshot" class to show tooltip. This is the problem. To resolve this, you have to bind event with "tr" instead of "a" tag within "td". So my suggestion is,

```
//Bind the event with "tr" and delegate the event to "a" tag
$('tr').on('mouseenter','td a[rel]', function(e) {
    this.t=this.title;
    this.title="";
    var c=(this.t!="")?"<br/>"+this.t:"";
    $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='"+this.rel+"' alt='Drinkbak' />"+c+"</p>");
    $("#screenshot").css("top",(e.pageY-xOffset)+"px").css("left",(e.pageX+yOffset)+"px").fadeIn("fast");
})
```

Note: I haven't tested my code and added function to handle mouse leave. I left these things to you.

Comment: When I try that, the image does stay when the <a> element is hovered and I move the mouse anywhere else within the <tr> element, but not when the <tr> element is hovered elsewhere. I'd like the image to show when someone hovers the <tr> element, and not has to hover the <a> element first. Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look this http://jsfiddle.net/aUfru/1/. Here I have done some JS which is very basic. Hopefully you will get an idea to resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks hilarudeens, that jsfiddle gave me the answer! Thanks a lot :)